# How to replace " [ ] ' " with blank space from a string ['flag = no'] with python

Tags: python, string, replace, python-3.5

Trying to replace the bracket and single quotes with space using re.sub, its throwing error from ['flag = no']

```
import re
import subprocess
#string to search text
lst = r'(flask) C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-enter code heretion>python secureassistchk.py flag = no'
#search flag = no within string & return "['flag = no']
dat = re.findall('flag.*', lst)
print("Print FLAG:", dat)
# replace [' with blank space , this doesn't work
#dat3 = re.sub('[\(\)\{\}<>]', '', dat)
#dat3 = re.sub('\b[]\b','', dat)
dat3 = re.sub('[ ]','',dat)
print("Print FLAG:", dat3)
```

Comment: And what error its throwing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here, I fixed it for you:

Code:

`dat3 = re.sub('\[|\]','', str(dat))
print("Print FLAG:", dat3)`

Result:

```
"'flag = no'"
```

**Edit:**

Ok, I missed the part about quotes. This is the corrected regex:

```
dat3 = re.sub('\[|\]|\'','', str(dat))
```

The first problem in your initial query was explained by Maciek:
dat is not a string object.

The second problem with your query was that the character you want to replace must be escaped with a \ if they are special characters. You must also chain them with a pipe (a.k.a '|' character).

For example, if you want to add white spaces to your list of replaced characters, the regex will be changed to:

```
dat3 = re.sub('\[|\]|\'| ','', str(dat))
```

You should notice the additional pipe and space character.

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by the fact that `dat` is a list, not a string.

Try:

```
dat = re.findall('flag.*', lst)[0]
```